# How does the induction proof work in this example?

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, induction

Refer to answer 1.1 of this file: http://www.dei.unipd.it/~geppo/AA/DOCS/NPC.pdf

> [image]

From my understanding and this thread, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/928412, we need 3 steps for that proof.
The first case is trivial and true. Now we have assumed the same for `i` and going to prove that it is true for `i+1`. I'm unable to clearly see how they have made that deduction in this answer.

Comment: Are you asking why $O( (p^i(n))^k ) = O(p^{i+1}(n))$?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: What *specifically* do you not understand?